# Can't use shell commands using python (jupyter)

Tags: python, jupyter

I'm trying to install scrot package by apt-get using python on jupyter. The server that I'm trying to make install is an online access jupyter, I don't have direct shell access. So I have to use python for this installation.

I used:

`import os
stream = os.popen('apt-get install -y scrot')
output = stream.read()
output`

And:

`from subprocess import check_call, CalledProcessError
import os
try:
    check_call(['apt-get', 'install', '-y', 'scrot'], stdout=open(os.devnull,'wb')) 
except CalledProcessError as e: 
    print(e.output)`

I used those and codes like them. But they just don't work. No errors, nothing. So I can't determine the problem. Can you help please ?

Comment: So, it works outside of Jupyter?

Comment: @Ivan I don't think so but I don't know exactly sir, I have jupyter notebook screen infront of me and I'm just trying to install a package. And when I try those it gives no output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you execute a command in OS you use the user that is running the jupyter server.
For apt-get something you will need root access, and it's very improbable that the jupyter server is running with that permissions.

Comment: So it is unsolvable with writing a code on python huh ? :/

Comment: I think so. Any server with remote access and root permissions is a serious security hole.